# Question 24 should have an "N/A" option

Tags: discussion, bug, survey, survey-2017

See the following "circled" question:

[image: question]

The circled question reads:

> It’s harder to collaborate with remote peers than those on site

However I have never, as of yet, had to collaborate remotely therefore I need a N/A option as I have no experience on the matter. How do I answer this?

Note that question 27 has a similar N/A option:

[image]

Comment: Just leave it blank.

Comment: @Rizier123 Didn't realise I could! Either way this could be made clearer

Comment: The more conspicuous absence is a "neutral" option for *all* of the choices!

Comment: @CodyGray Of cource, when I answered I just used "Somewhat Agree" as neutral but it didn't feel right

Comment: @CodyGray Also no "Somewhat disagree". Apparently you can kind of agree that it's better to ship now and optimize later, but by gum, you better fully disagree!